# Dynamically set a named LOV against a select list page item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX v4.2 on Oracle 11g DB.

I currently have a page item (P10_JOB_INFO), which is a select list with a pre-assigned Named LOV (i.e. JOBS_LOV) under the page item's List of Values section.

What I would like to achieve and unsure if possible is based on a radio group selection via a Dynamic Action change/click, switch the Named LOV currently assigned to P10_JOB_INFO to now use another Named LOV such as MGR_JOB_LOV.

Is this possible via a Dynamic Action and/or Oracle APEX API?

Comment: Create another List (initially hidden) and use the radio group to hide/show each list item via dynamic action or onchange event. Changing dynamically a named LOV is not possible, you could use a query to change the options based on the radio group value though

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create another list as this page item is actually sourced off a Database column and you can't have more than one page items reference the same database column.

Comment: I see, then I'd go with changing the LOV definition to a query that uses the radio group value as a parameter, and refreshing it on change